# Resize the browser's width using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking for a way to resize the Chrome browser's width with a button. Preferentially using JQuery. My goal is to show the mobile version of the website to desktop users.

I know I can do this by just resizing the BODY tag (which is definitely easier) but I got curious.

I haven't found reliable answers to this question and sorry if it has already been asked.

Other ideas are always welcome.

Thanks. :)

Comment: `$('body').width(500)` doesn't seem to do anything. Are you sure that resizing the body tag does what you say?

Comment: $("#button").click(function() {
        $("body").animate({
            width: '360px'
        }, 1000);
    });
This should do the work I guess. You got me curious I need to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent browsers (since FF7) aren't going to support window.resizeTo(x,y) unless it's a window you created that doesn't have any other tabs. This is to prevent abusive website code.

Check the notes on this [MDN Window.resizeTo() help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo):

> Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a window in a browser, according to the following rules:
>
> You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
>
> You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

Like you mentioned, you can launch a new window with a specified size to preview a mobile experience. Alternatively, you could create an IFrame with a specified size:

```
<iframe src="/mobile" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Thanks that's probably why I haven't found anything lol
Opening a new window is probably not the best option UX-wise but the solution works.
Thanks again for your help  :)

Answer (score 0):

As Pranspach mentioned you can't resize the actual chrome window, but if your site is responsive on resize you could wrap the whole site in a wrapper div and shrink that instead of body.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm gonna do
Thanks :)